# USB keyboard not working on linux(Archlinux) but works on bios

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, arch-linux

I'm trying to connect a usb keyboard to my labtop but it's not working after boot into linux(working fine on bios and windows 10 on other pc).
It's detected in `lsusb`,

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b649 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0853:0132 Topre Corporation TYPE HEAVEN 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's what I found after plug-in the keyboard in `dmesg | tail`

```
[ 1198.605513] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0853, idProduct=0132, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1198.605518] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1198.605521] usb 1-1: Product: TYPE HEAVEN 
[ 1198.605524] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Topre Corporation
[ 1198.605792] usb 1-1: no configuration chosen from 0 choices
```

Is the problem there? my laptop has only usb3.0 slots fyi.

Any solution, I cannot find any workaround.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you try passing the `usbcore.quirks` kernel parameter? [USB keyboard not working after boot but works on bios](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251844)

Comment: @lx07 Yes, I'm the one who asking there. It's working fine now!

Comment: BIOS has its own USB stack, that's why your keyboard works in BIOS. The OS usually has its own set of drivers, and apparently you have only root hub driver in your Linux, but the HID device driver is somehow missing.